# Does Azure AD B2C allow login on the custom domain login page instead of https://<tenant-name>.b2clogin.com page?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have registered an application in Azure AD B2C. Once try to access the application's login URL(E.g. - https://contoso.com/api/v1/login), it redirects the request to Azure AD B2C URL(E.g. - https://contoso.b2clogin.com). On successful login it redirects to the application home page(E.g. -https://contoso.com/api/v1/home).

Is it possible to achieve the same functionality by providing the user's login credentials on the application login page(https://contoso.com/api/v1/login) itself and not redirecting to the Azure AD B2C login page? The backend application can validate the user using Azure AD B2C URL behind the scene and return the authentication token on successful login.

Please suggest and provide some node js code if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **B2C Custom domains** for a better user experience:
[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-domain?pivots=b2c-user-flow

Update:

[Using MSAL 2.0 without implicit flow in your app registration allows it](https://mikaberglund.com/blazor-authentication-with-blazorade-msal-an-overview/) opening a popup.

Node info [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-node/README.md).

Comment: He is looking for REST API or SDK API kind of support of AD B2C to pass user name, password and other information, and get the session token after successful  login. This shall happen without any redirection, meaning from a different app. It is okay if that app needs to be registered with AD B2C instance.

Answer (score -1):

It is possibe by using ROPC flow - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-ropc-policy?tabs=app-reg-ga&pivots=b2c-user-flow

You should keep in mind though that OAuth2 best practice discourages from using this flow - https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics-13#section-3.4